# CNN parameter estimate

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to design a CNN for a binary image classification task, which is to detect a small object present or absent in the images. The images are greyscale (unsigned short) with size 512x512 (dowmsampled from 2048x2048 already), and I have thousands of those images for training and test.

It's my first time using CNN for this kind of task, and I hope to achieve ~80% accuracy to start, so I'd like to know, IN GENERAL, how to design the CNN such that I have the best chance to achieve my goal.

My specific questions are:

1. How many convolution layers and fully-connected layers should I use?
2. How many feature maps are in each convolution layer and how many nodes in each fully-connected layer?
3. What's the filter size in each convolution layer?

I'm trying to implement the CNN using Keras with TensorFlow backend, and my computer's specs are: 8 Intel Xeon CPUs @ 3.5 GHz; 32 GB memory; 2 Nvidia GPUs: GeForce GTX 980 and Quadro K4200

With those hardware and software, I'd also like to know the computational time of the training. Specifically,

How long will it take to train the CNN (with above structure) with 1000 images mentioned above in epoch, and (in general) how many epochs are needed to achieve ~80% accuracy?

The reason I want to know the typical computational time is to make sure I set up everything properly.

Hope I didn't ask too many questions in my first post.

Comment: you ask about parameters of neural network, there are no "IN GENERAL" answer for this question, especially with different dataset. You need to find the best parameters by experiments

Comment: @malioboro OK, if there is no general answer, could you shed light from your experience?

Comment: You can get some general advice on setting CNN parameters from Stanford CS231n course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably go very well if you take one of the already existing models that keras makes available for that task, such as VGG16, VGG19, InceptionV3 and others: https://keras.io/applications/.

You may experiment on them, try different paramters, little tweaks here and there, and stuff like that. Since you've got only one class, you can probably try smaller versions of them.

All the codes can be found in https://github.com/fchollet/keras/tree/master/keras/applications

Speed is very very relative. It's impossible to tell the speed because each installation method, each driver, each version, each operational system may or may not actually use your hardware capabilities properly or entirely.

But with your specifications, it should be pretty fast, if everything is set up well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Dan. When you say "it should be pretty fast", you mean a few seconds of a few minutes per epoch? The reason I ask is to make sure I set up everything right.

Comment: What is the size of the images? It should take a few seconds "per batch" with 1 big image (1200x1800) or with several small images covering a similar area in pixels. At least that's what I achieved on Google VMs with a Tesla K80. But it does depend a lot on the size of the model though. My model had around 10million trainable parameters.